# Stack switch with HSRP for Gateway redundancy

Tags: cisco, switch, redundancy, stacking, hsrp

We have `ws-c3850-48t` two switch in stack. and from Internet Provide `ISP` we have two fiber drops coming for redundancy. I want to configure HSRP for failover but i believe stack switch work like single virtual switch. so I am confused whether it is doable or not or if yes then how it will work?

```
    _________________
   [_______ISP_______]
     |             |
     |             | 
 10G |             | 10G  (links) 
   ___________________
  [__ 2x stack SW ____]
```

Question:

```
Q1. Does `HSRP` suggestible on stack switches?
Q2. Is there any alternation for gateway redundancy?
```

**Update:** I am getting `/30` IP pool for handoff and `/23` IP pool for my server firm from my ISP.

So that way i have to configure IP address on my `L3` switch port and configure `HSRP` right to failover right??

Comment: A stacked switch is effectively a single switch. If you've got two fibre links from the same ISP, have them set up BGP, It's trivial when both links are from the same ISP (I'd check to ensure that the links are going to two separate PoPs, or at least two different network segments in the same PoP)

Comment: Yes that link coming from same ISP but its just physical fiber link.. it is just for standby, in case fiber cut for switch fail.. we have second link to run packets....

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

HSRP would be configured on the ISP side, not your side.

The switch will look and be configured like a single switch.

You will use the `no switchport` command on the two interfaces to the ISP. Each interface would be configured as a router interface and each would have an IP address. It will look something like this:

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/0
 no switchport
 ip address 1.1.1.2 255.255.255.252
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 no cdp enable
 no shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/0
 no switchport
 ip address 2.2.2.2 255.255.255.252
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 no cdp enable
 no shutdown
!
```

Since you are now considering using a port channel:

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/0
 no switchport
 no ip address
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 no cdp enable
 channel-group 1 mode on
 no shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0/0
 no switchport
 no ip address
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 no cdp enable
 channel-group 1 mode on
 no shutdown
!
interface PortChannel1
 no switchport
 ip address 1.1.1.2 255.255.255.252
 no ip redirects
 no ip unreachables
 no ip proxy-arp
 no cdp enable
 no shutdown
!
```

**Note:**

You *really* should have a firewall between the ISP and your switch stack. Also, you can't use NAT on the switch, you would need a router for that.

Comment: Why not configure `HSRP` on my side? I am getting `handoff` IP and then `server` IP pool from ISP `/23`. its `L3` switch so i have to configure IP address on sw port and terminate ISP link. so i can create subnet and and play with `/23` subnet.

Comment: We are running `iptables` firewall on all hosts, so we don't have dedicated firewalls.

Comment: I would happy if you solve my existing problem.. i will deal with security later. Believe me whatever we are dealing right now it has `zero` security issue. I need things working. I just want to know how i can have redundancy with stack switch...

Comment: So you suggesting, terminate two fiber on `stack switch` and configure IP address on both fiber ports right?  and then configure IP route to with `100`  and `200` weight ??  am i right?   what if one of my stack switch failed?

Comment: In even in that case i have to configure VLAN and assign IP address to switch port which is connected to ISP router right?

Comment: Sounds good! lets say i have all my servers `gateway` will be my `L3 switch` so in that case if one switch fail then my all servers `gateway` fill failed right?  In this case i need to configure `HSRP` interface so my host can talk to `HSRP` IP address right? what do you suggest?

Comment: Holy! crap!! now you hit hammer on nail.. I was thinking stack is just for management. like you have single console to access all switch.. but now you are saying it is single switch and can do failover itself.... Interesting...

Comment: Last question. if i termination fiber on two switch port `G1/0/0` and `G2/0/0` in that case do i need to configure TWO ip address on both port of just configured single `vlanX` ip address and add `vlanX` to both port G1 and G2 port and configure  routing as you mentioned in your answer right?

Comment: This is what i know from ISP. they gave me two link with two WAN IP address. lets say `1.1.1.4` & `1.1.1.5`  and their `HSRP` address is `1.1.1.1` so my default gateway would be `1.1.1.1`. so question is do i configure just single IP address `1.1.1.4` (SVI)  and route traffic on G1 & G2 port or configure `1.1.1.4` & `1.1.1.5` on my switch as SVI and bind them on G1 & G2 related switch ports.. what do you suggest?

Comment: But on L3 switch we can't configure IP address on switch port right? It has to be on `vlanX` IP address right?  how can i configure same subnet IP on two `vlan` interface?

Comment: I love this conversation which clear many doubts! Let me try this setup on `GNS3` and see how it goes.. it would be good if you give me email address so i can shoot email if i need more info..

Comment: Can you give the exact IP/mask you have? AFAIK a /30 is not enough IP for hsrp to work, and two disjoint /30 won't work either. You need a /29.

Comment: And btw, 1.1.1.0/24 should not be used for examples: this is real public IP range. You'd better use 192.0.2.0/24. See RFC 5737.

Comment: I used the addresses provided by the OP. I would not use such addresses as examples. The OP and I had a conversation in [chat]. HSRP cannot be configured on the remote site for the ISP, it must be configured on the ISP side for the remote side. The OP decided to ask the ISP to use a port channel. The OP was unaware that a stack of switches is really a single logical switch and wanted to configure HSRP on it for the local LAN, but that will not work with a single device.